# WordPress term_exists returning null when term does exist

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

I'm investigating an issue with WPAllImport plugin and the issue seems to be related to Wordpress core function **term_exists** . I think I'm passing the right arguments but not getting the expected response.

I attached an image showing the **get_term** working fine showing all the details to this term.. while the **term_exists** passing the exact data where it should (by parent) returns null:
[image]

I looked around similar tickets but most are passing incorrect arguments unlike this case. Does anyone know if this is an issue with Wordpress or am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are doing something wrong.  1) Posting picture: see: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)  2) Read the number again `16736` vs. `16735` ?   and 3) https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the pointless comments. 16735 is the parent ID. The function term_exists expects the parent ID for the 3rd optional argument https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_exists/ . And the image speaks a thousand words.

Comment: ok, sorry, I must be deaf to reading pictures..... (screensize: 1366x768; picturesize: way larger..... ==> scroll bars...)

Comment: Thank you nonetheless for your contribution. I highlighted the parent ID from the get_term towards the 3rd argument on purpose to clearly indicate it's correct and in integer type

Comment: Just ruling things out here... does it work when you use the ID `16736` instead of the name? That field is supposed to be able to take ID, slug or name, so switching it up might give us insight into the issue.

Comment: Also, I noticed there are filters that can affect how `term_exists()` works. Have you taken the step of disabling all other plugins and switching to a default theme to rule that out? Also searching the files within this plugin for the filter `term_exists_default_query_args` could rule out that happening.

Comment: Thank you @Stevish, I checked everywhere for that filter with no results. I tried with the ID as you suggested which worked.. So I went ahead and since I only have the title of the category at hand, loaded all category terms by name and looped the result calling term_exists using the ID and the parent ID as the relation between term and it's parent is important. This hack has fixed my issue, thanks again.